# How to get ListView Item Id

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have this ListView with TextBock and CheckBox:

```
<ListView x:Name="ActiveTasksListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveTasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding Id}">

<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="37,0,17,0" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click_1" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

If I click on CheckBox than I need to show Id (from datasource) of clicked item in MessageDialog()

Comment: where do you need to show the `Id` in the `TextBlock`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: have you tried getting it by the `ListView.Items["key"]` or can you not get at the `Tag` Property..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as CheckBox;
    dynamic itemVM = cb.DataContext;
    var id = itemVM.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VisualTreeHelper and clicked CheckBox element you can find ListViewItem and then get its Id property

```
void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as DependencyObject;

    while (!(item is ListViewItem))
    {
        item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    }

    var id = ((ObjectClass) item).Id;
}
```